# Android Studio Stopping/Killing Timer with Switch Statement

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

What I've built is a timer with multiple timer styles, using a spinner so the user can switch quickly between the timer they want to use.

My problem is with the switch statement - each timer works fine on its own but when going (example) from the Basic Timer to the Countdown Timer via the spinner, the first timer (Basic Timer) continues being run alongside the newly selected timer. In this example, the bug displays as 1 second down 1 second up 1 second down 1 second up etc...

My questions is: Is there a command that can be used to "kill" a function that I no longer want to continue running? If not, is there a better way I could have organized the code so the switch statements will keep each timer process separate? I have tried a Boolean check with no luck and breaking up the timer running-specific code differently has not worked for me so far.

Please see the relevant code below:

```
package com.mtag.app.muaythaiathletesguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private int seconds = 0; // Number of seconds passed
    private boolean running; // Check whether timer is running
    private boolean wasRunning;

    private int timeCap = 0; // Custom max time, stop timer when reached and reset here for countdown

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

        // Timer Selection Spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timer_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.timer_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Restore activity's state by getting values from Bundle
        if (savedInstanceState != null && running) {
            seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
            running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
            wasRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("wasRunning");
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        String selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        // TODO: Remove Toast outputs after testing
        // Call Timer types when corresponding position is chosen
        switch(pos) {
            case 0: // Basic Stopwatch: Count from 0:00:00 to 99:59:59 (or cap)
                onDestroy();
                running = false; // Stop clock
                seconds = 0; // Reset seconds to zero
                timeCap = seconds; // Set time cap to match seconds on the clock, for reset point
                runBasicTimer();
                break;
            case 1: // Countdown: Count from 99:59:59 (or cap) to 0:00:00
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                onDestroy();
                running = false;
                seconds = 1200; // Default cap 20:00:00
                timeCap = seconds;
                runCountdownTimer();
                break;
            case 2: // Tabata: Beep every 20th and 30th second. Reset to 0:00:00 on each 30th second
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                running = false;
                seconds = 0;
                runTabataTimer();
                break;
            case 3: // Fight Gone Bad: 17min cap, beep on each minute
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                running = false;
                seconds = 0;
                runFGBTimer();
                break;
            case 4: // "3 On 1 Off": Beep every 3rd and 4th minute
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                running = false;
                seconds = 0;
                runThreeOneTimer();
                break;
            case 5: // "5 On 1 Off": Beep every 5th and 6th minute
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                running = false;
                seconds = 0;
                runFiveOneTimer();
                break;
            default:
                running = false;
                seconds = 0;
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
        // Another interface callback
    }

    @Override
    // Save the state of variables
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("seconds", seconds);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("running", running);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("wasRunning", wasRunning);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // If the stopwatch was running at stop, set it running again
        if (wasRunning)
            running = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Record state of stopwatch, running or not running
        wasRunning = running;
        running = false;
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {
        running = true; // Start stopwatch
    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) {
        running = false; // Stop stopwatch
    }

    public void onClickReset(View view) {
        seconds = timeCap; // Reset seconds to zero
    }

    private void runBasicTimer() {
        final TextView timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int hours = seconds / 3600;
                int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                int secs = seconds % 60;

                // Format time to hours, minutes, and seconds
                String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs);
                timeView.setText(time);

                if (running) {
                    seconds++;
                }
                // Don't allow timer to go over 99:59:59
                if (seconds >= 359999) {
                    running = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum time reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Post code again with delay of one second
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void runCountdownTimer() {
        final TextView timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int hours = seconds / 3600;
                int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                int secs = seconds % 60;

                // Format time to hours, minutes, and seconds
                String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs);
                timeView.setText(time);

                if (running) {
                    seconds--;
                }
                // Don't allow timer to go under 0:00:00
                if (seconds <= 1) {
                    running = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum time reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Post code again with delay of one second
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void runTabataTimer() {

    }

    private void runFGBTimer() {

    }

    private void runThreeOneTimer() {

    }

    private void runFiveOneTimer() {

    }
}
```

And here's the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="com.mtag.app.muaythaiathletesguide.TimerActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/timer_style"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timer_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGrey"
        android:minHeight="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textSize="90sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTimerGreen"
            android:onClick="onClickStart"
            android:text="@string/start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTimerRed"
            android:onClick="onClickStop"
            android:text="@string/stop" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="onClickReset"
            android:text="@string/reset" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: please mark an answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer/countdown is running on another thread. That is okay by itself but comes with provisions that you have missed. For example, you are trying to set `running` and `seconds` when a new item is selected. Those two variables exist in the context of your UI thread. When they are used in the `Runnable` they are simply put, copied as final variables and used by the new thread. This happens when you reference a variable inside an anonymous class. This causes the `Runnable` to not see the variables you are changing because they are not the same anymore.

Now how to fix this?

Instead of passing an anonymous `Runnable`, you should hold a reference to it. Right now, you are creating a timer and just letting it go. That makes it very hard to control it as you can see.

```
Runnable activeTimer;

private void runBasicTimer() {
    //... first remove any other activeTimer if exists and make sure it is cancelled properly (see below)
    activeTimer = new Runnable() {//Your code}
    handler.post(activeTimer);
}
```

This way you can always remove the `activeTimer` from the `Handler` [like this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

This is still not complete. Because you also repost the runnable regularly. We also want to cancel that as well so that it is not reposted to the handler. To do this you should extend the `Runnable` class so that you can change `running` in it.

```
public class TimerRunnable extends Runnable {
    public boolean mRunning = true;


    @Override
    public void run() {
     //your code
     if (mRunning) {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
     }
    }
```

}

Now when you want to create a new timer:

```
activeTimer = new TimerRunnable(); //instead of just new Runnable()
```

Perfect! Now you can easily cancel it because you have access to its thread and you have access to the thread's `mRunning` variable. In your `onItemSelected` instead of just changing `running` you can do this:

```
 if (activeTimer != null) {
    activeTimer.mRunning = false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth response - this is excellent. I have one more question though, as I implement what you've taught me.

I am unsure where to add the public class TimerRunnable, as my run() code is within each of the individual timer styles and my handler is declared within the corresponding runTimer methods.

Comment: You can define it in a different file. But the trick is the dependencies (variables that you refer to from inside run). You should create getters and setters inside the TimerRunnable to be able to pass any dependencies. Except for `timeView`. Because `timeView` is a UI element and needs to run on the main thread, it is better if you keep it in the activity and set it using a callback